Pytorch dtype help need
#i got this csv file from kaggle(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/keplersmachines/kepler-labelled-time-series-#data?resource=download)
train_df = pd.read_csv("../csvs/Space Travel/Exoplanet Hunting in Deep Space/1/exoTrain.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("../csvs/Space Travel/Exoplanet Hunting in Deep Space/1/exoTest.csv")

X_train_df = train_df.drop(["LABEL"], axis = 1).values
print(X_train_df.shape)
X_train_df

y_train_df = train_df["LABEL"].values.reshape(-1,1).squeeze()
print(y_train_df.shape)
y_train_df

X_train , X_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X_train_df,
                                                       y_train_df,
                                                       test_size=0.2,
                                                       train_size=0.8,
                                                       shuffle=True,
                                                       random_state=123)

sc = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

print(f"max of train_data is {X_train.max()} \
    and X_test max is {X_test.max()} \
        and min is {X_train.min()} \
            X_test min : {X_test.min()} \
                same with y labels : {y_train.max()} \
                    y_test max : {y_test.max()} \
                        y_train min : {y_train.min()} \
                            and : {y_test.min()}")

X_train.shape[1]

print(type(X_train))
print(type(X_test))
print(type(y_train))
print(type(y_train))

#X_train = T.from_numpy(X_train).int()
#X_test = T.from_numpy(X_test).int()
#y_train = T.from_numpy(y_train).int()
#y_test = T.from_numpy(y_test).int()

X_train = T.from_numpy(X_train).float()
X_test = T.from_numpy(X_test).float()
y_train = T.from_numpy(y_train).float()
y_test = T.from_numpy(y_test).float()

#X_train = T.tensor(X_train , dtype = T.long)
#X_test =T.tensor(X_test , dtype = T.long)
#y_train = T.tensor(y_train , dtype = T.long)
#y_test =T.tensor(y_test , dtype = T.long)

print(type(X_train))
print(type(X_test))
print(type(y_train))
print(type(y_train))

class Exoplanet_AI(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, input_dims = X_train.shape[1] , hidden_units = 125 , output_dims = X_train.shape[1]):
        super().__init__()
        self.activation = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.droprate = (0.2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p = self.droprate)
        self.flaten = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.ll1 = nn.Linear(in_features = input_dims , out_features = hidden_units)
        self.ll2 = nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_units, out_features = hidden_units)
        
        self.ll3 = nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_units , out_features = hidden_units)
        self.ll4 = nn.Linear(in_features = hidden_units, out_features = output_dims)
        
        self.compute_probability = nn.Softmax(dim = 1)
        
    def forward(self , X):
        X = self.flaten(X)
        X = self.activation(self.ll1(X))
        X = self.activation(self.ll2(X))
        X = self.dropout(X)
        X = self.activation(self.ll3(X))
        X = self.activation(self.ll4(X))
        X = self.compute_probability(X)
        
        return X

class train_and_testing():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.device = T.device("cuda:0" if T.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.lr = 1e-3
        self.epochs = 20
        
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.y_test = y_test
        
        self.model = Exoplanet_AI().to(self.device)
        self.criterion = opt.Adam(params = self.model.parameters() , lr = self.lr)
        self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        
    def parameters(self):
        return self.model.state_dict()
        
    def train_loop(self):
        
        current_loss = 0.0
        
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            self.model.train()
            
            forward_pass = self.model(self.X_train)
            
            loss_fn = self.loss(forward_pass , self.y_train)
            
            loss_fn.backward()
            
            self.criterion.step()
            
            self.criterion.zero_grad()
            
            current_loss += loss_fn.item()
            
            print(f"On epochs {i} the loss is {loss_fn}")

train_and_testing().parameters()

train_and_testing().train_loop()

my error is:
you can see in my code i tryd so much to change the dtype into the corrent dtype but everytime i got another into another into another dtype error :( and absolutely dont know how to fix the dtype error :(
    and as error i get :
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[28], line 1
    ----> 1 train_and_testing().train_loop()
    
    Cell In[26], line 57
         53 self.model.train()
         55 forward_pass = self.model(self.X_train)
    ---> 57 loss_fn = self.loss(forward_pass , self.y_train)
         59 loss_fn.backward()
         61 self.criterion.step()
    
    packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
       1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
       1510 else:
    -> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
    
   

packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
1516 # this function, and just call forward.
1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
1522 try:
...
3057 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
3058     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3059 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
    RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
    Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings


Please provide the full error message associated with this code.

nn.CrossEntropyLoss expects target values to have LongTensor dtype.
Your code calls y_train = T.from_numpy(y_train).float(), casting the target values to float type.
To cast to long type, use y_train = T.from_numpy(y_train).long()
